# Doubt concerning proof of Lusin's theorem for abstract Hausdorff locally compact measure space

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am currently reading Cohn's book "Measure Theory". In page 208 of the second edition, the following theorem is proven:

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra which includes Borel's $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ a regular measure on $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is such that $\mu(A) < \infty$, and $\epsilon$ is a positive number, then there exists a compact subset $K$ of $A$ such that $\mu(A - K ) < \epsilon$ and $f|_K$ is continuous.

The proof first shows that the theorem is valid when $f(X)$ is countable, as follows: If $f(X) = \{ a_1,a_2, \dots\}$ and $A_n = f^{-1}(\{a_n\}) $ for each natural $n$, by continuity of $\mu$ there exists $k$ integer such that $\mu (A - (\cup_{j=1}^k A_j)) < \epsilon /2$. By regularity, there exists compact sets $K_j \subset A \cap A_j$ for $j=1 ,\dots, k$ such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^k \mu ( (A\cap A_j) - K_j)) < \epsilon/2$$

Thus, if $K = \cup_{j=1}^k K_j$,
$$ \mu(A - K ) < \mu (A -  \cup_{j=1}^k A_j) +\sum_{j=1}^k \mu ( (A\cap A_j) - K_j) < \epsilon $$

Thus, as each restriction $f|_{K_j}$ is continuous, $f|_K$ is continuous.
When $f(X)$ is arbitrary, it constructs a sequence $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ which converges to $f$ uniformily on $X$ in the following manner: for each natural $n$ and $x \in X$ there exists an integer $k_x^{(n)}$ such that
$$ k_x^{(n)}/n \leq f(x) < (k_x^{(n)} +1)/n. $$
Define then $f_n(x) = k_x^{(n)}/n$.
Thus the sequence of functions converges uniformily to $f$ in $X$ and each $f_n$ maps $X$ to a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, by the first case, there exists a compact subset $K_n$ of $A$ such that $\mu(A - K_n) < \epsilon /2^n$. However, to construct the compact set of the thesis of the theorem, it defines $K = \cap_{n=1}^\infty K_n$, which, I am not so sure it should be non-empty. Can someone help me on why $K$ should or should not be empty?

Comment: Look at the measure of its compliment

Comment: @FZan Its complement has $\infty$ as measure, but, does this imply that the set itself has positive measure?

Comment: The compliment in $A$

Comment: Got it, thank you